# How to avoid slow query if data is too big for one partition in NoSQL?

Tags: sql, cassandra, nosql, bigdata, data-modeling

I am learning cassandra. Now, I am thinking about SQL's problems that NoSQL addresses, and I have a question about cases of very big data.

About SQL handling very big data, I thought that many pages are saying that tables will be on different servers and queries are slow because of joining tables on different servers. This is a problem of SQL that NoSQL addresses. But, even with NoSQL, if partitions are too big, do not I need to change my data model, make smaller partitions and make multiple queries on them to get the same result? And, is not it slow? Or, you never run out of a space in partition because 2B cells are big enough?

Answer (score 4):

I think your question is mixing several different issues.

First of all, the problem with big data and SQL is usually not that queries become slow, but that the solution cannot scale as the data grows bigger and bigger. If you choose to manually split your tables to several servers, as you suggested, what do you do when you need even more servers - redesign your data model? Also, how do you ensure consistency when an update requires modifying several tables but they are on different hosts?

Second, you mentioned joins, and this is something which NoSQL solutions like Cassandra do **not** support. You need to manually denormalize the data yourself (i.e., put the already joined data in a table). For some things, Cassandra's new "Materialized Views" feature can come in handy.

Third, and perhaps most importantly, you asked about huge partitions. Indeed Cassandra is not designed to handle huge partitions, and the best practice is far below the 2-billion hard limit which you mentioned: Datastax (the commercial company behind Cassandra's development) suggests in https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse-planning/doc/planning/planningPartitionSize.html that a good rule of thumb is to "keep the maximum number of rows below 100,000 items and the disk size under 100 MB.".

There are several reasons why huge partitions are ill-advised in Cassandra. One of them is that the disk format (sstables and their so-called "promoted index") makes it inefficient to jump to the middle of a huge partition, and you need to do this when you want to read a specific row or iterate through all the rows. Some operations such as compaction and repair work on entire partitions and can become very slow (and in the worst case, also use a lot of memory). E.g., a case that a billion-row partition differs on two nodes by just one row, and the partition-based repair needs to send the entire partition over the network.

Scylla (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scylla_(database)), a Cassandra clone which is generally more efficient than Apache Cassandra, also has similar issues with huge partitions (as in Cassandra, moderately large partitions are fine), but these issues are actively being worked on, including re-designing the file format, so eventually Scylla should support arbitrary-sized partitions. However, we're still not there yet, and today the recommendation of not letting partitions grow too huge still applies to Scylla as well.

Finally, if you want to get around the problem of too many rows in a single partition, then, yes, you need to tweak your data model to avoid these huge partitions. Sometimes, you just need to fix design mistakes in your model - e.g., I have seen people sticking a lot of unrelated data into the same partition, when it could have easily (and more efficiently!) be put in separate partitions. Sometimes, you need to artificially split your partitions. This is common in so-called "time-series data" modeling in Cassandra, where we (for example) get a new value of some measurement every second and add it as a row to a partition. Here, instead of having one huge partition for all data ever, the accepted practice is to create a separate partition per time window (e.g., a new partition every day, or week, or whatever). Since most queries involve just one time window anyway, they don't even become slower.